# ASP.NET MVC errors - controller and/or action method not found

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to identify the source for error messages logged by ELMAH in an ASP.NET MVC 5.2 application.

There are two distinct errors:

1. A public action method 'null' was not found on controller.
2. A public action method 'undefined' was not found on controller.

I can not recreate these errors locally or on staging/testing environments and no end users are complaining of any issues.

All the 'undefined' errors seem to be requesting images.

```
HTTP_ACCEPT: "image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,image/svg+xml,image/*,*/*;q=0.8"
```

And all the 'null' errors are requesting anything.

```
HTTP_ACCEPT: "*/*"
```

All the recorded errors are ALWAYS for `REQUEST_METHOD: GET`.

These errors occur for all controllers in the application.

Since "null" and "undefined" are both JavaScript values, I initially suspected that JavaScript was used to define a route but I have confirmed that is not the case. I do use jQuery Ajax on several screens but this error occurs on screens where no jQuery Ajax calls are made.

This application also contains Google Analytics script on every page.

```
<script>window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}gtag('js', new Date());gtag('config', 'G-XXX');</script>
```

Any ideas? What additional information can I provide to help troubleshoot?

Comment: Some additional context... this application has recorded 42 million page views in the last four weeks (via Google Analytics) with 3,067 recorded ELMAH errors as defined in the post within the same time period.  Could this be an issue with a browser extension requesting resources?

Comment: is your application public? this could be just bots scanning website for vulnerabilities.